# Why do they have no convex drawing?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Recently I am learning the basic knowledge of drawing theory of planar graph, and I refer to the following book.

***Nishizeki, Takao, and Md Saidur Rahman. Planar graph drawing. Vol. 12. World Scientific, 2004.***

A **straight line drawing** of a plane graph $G$  is called a ***convex drawing*** if the boundaries of all faces of $G$ are drawn as convex polygons, as illustrated in following picture.[image]

There is an exercise on page 16 of the book about showing that the following three graphs  **have no convex drawing**.

Obviously, the third graph with multiple edges cannot be drawn with straight lines drawing.
So there must have no convex drawing. **But for the first two, I have not yet explained why they do not have convex drawing.**
[image]

Comment: Connected, by the same author: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1088.6028&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks for recommending ! I will read this paper.